# Authorization with Meteor and React-router

Tags: meteor, react-router

I'm using the react-router package to handle routes in a Meteor app, and I'd like to check if the user is logged in and is authorized to see specific routes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out [Base](https://github.com/themeteorchef/base) - it's an awesome Meteor boilerplate. If you want to see how routing works specifically, checkout:

https://github.com/themeteorchef/base/blob/master/imports/startup/client/routes.js
https://github.com/themeteorchef/base/blob/master/imports/ui/containers/AppNavigation.js
https://github.com/themeteorchef/base/blob/master/imports/ui/components/AppNavigation.js